# How to put a reset button on zf2 forms?

Tags: forms, button, zend-framework2, reset

I know that are a lib

> 'Zend\Element\FormReset'

but dont are a Form class `Reset` like zf1. I dont know how to use it with form class to display a reset form button.

Answer (score 3):

create and add in your form a simple element class with `Zend\Form\Element`

```
$element = new \Zend\Form\Element('my-reset');
$element->setAttribute('value', 'Reset');
$this->add($element);
```

in your view use the `Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormReset` class to output a reset button

```
echo $this->formReset($element);
```

this will output

```
<input type="reset" name="my-reset" value="Reset">
```

Comment: I know this method from zf2 documentation, but I wanted a solution to put the reset button with the other elements in the $form object.

Comment: idk what u mean, you place it in your ``$form`` object and access it with ``$element = $form->get('my-reset');``

Comment: Yep, is it. this would be very practical.

Answer (score -1):

You can add reset button inside the form like this:

```
$this->add(
        [
            'type'       => 'Zend\Form\Element\Submit',
            'name'       => 'runReset',
            'attributes' => [
                'type'  => 'reset',
                'value' => 'Reset',
                'id'    => 'runReset',
                'class' => 'btn btn-default',
            ]
        ]
    );
```

Note the attibute 'type' is set to 'reset' while element is still Sumbit class. $this is the form object.

Calling:

```
echo $this->Form($form);
```

in the template produces following HTML:

```
<input type="reset" name="runReset" id="runReset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">
```